# Capybara select for a select-box populated dynamically using a db call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara, bdd

In my index view i have the following select box defined

```
 <%= select_tag('Country', options_for_select(@countries), :class => 'chosen-select') %>
```

The @countries is populated in the index controller as follows :

```
  @countries = CountryCode.uniq.pluck(:name)
```

So,as you see a database call is being made to fetch the list of country names to populate the select box.
Now, in my Cucumber steps defintion file i have

```
Then(/^I should see a select\-box for Countries$/) do
  select 'UNITED STATES', :from => 'Country'
end
```

This is giving me the error `Unable to find option "UNITED STATES" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)`
But when i check in browser the select box does have that option. Selecting elements using capybara for select-boxes with hardcoded option values is working fine, but in the above case when the options are fetched using a database call the step definition fails. How can i fix this ?

Please Help
Thank You

Comment: I think, Capybara taking some time to load the select box with countries list. you should try with sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is CountryCode an ActiveRecord model?  If so, the database is likely empty, which would explain why no values appear in your specs, but development works fine.

You may want to stub out the CountryCode call in the spec's Before hook with something like:

```
Before do
  arel_double = double(:arel)
  CountryCode.stub(:uniq).and_return(arel_double)
  arel_double.stub(:pluck).with(:name).and_return(['ARUBA', 'UNITED STATES'])
end
```

Exact syntax will depend on your stub library.

Comment: Fantastic !,that was the problem. Thanks a lot :)